# Overleaf and Section Fonts

Tags: fonts, sectioning, fontspec, titlesec

Oveleaf say that it's possible to use a set of pre-installed fonts 
 [here](https://it.overleaf.com/articles/slash-fontspec-all-the-fonts/qnsxyhrgjsgs). One of these is "CMU Classical Serif" I want to change the section title in my document to be "CMU Classical Serif"

I try the following, but the font does not change at all (using package titlesec, XeLaTex compiler for fontspec)

```latex
    \newfontfamily\sectionfonts{CMU Classical Serif}
    \titleformat*{\section}{ \center \large \bf}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bf} 
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\it}
```

Is this a problem with Overleaf or have I done something wrong?

Edit: there are no errors, not even "font not found", just no changes...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you ask the support of overleaf? They should know ...

Comment: `titlesec` doesn't use `\sectionfonts` directly, so you'll need to actually call it in your `\titleformat` perhaps?

Comment: unrelated but note that `\center` should never be used as a command form, I think you intended \centering`

Answer (score 1):

You are using the deprecated font commands such as `\bf` they will always use the *document* default encoding and family, they do not combine in the way that latex2e font commands do

Presumably you want something like

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\centering\sectionfonts\large\bfseries}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution: I just need to define a fontfamily separately and then call this inside \titelformat* as @LianTze Lim was suggesting, i.e:

```latex
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Alexander} 
 \titleformat{\section}{\headingfont \centering \large\bfseries}{\S \thesection.}{0.5em}{}[{\titlerule[0.2pt]}]
```

(the last parts are irrelevant). Thanks also to @DavidCarlisle, although I admit I haven't checked this :)